# Let PHP file read cookies when it it imported through readfile() function?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm loading my files using read file so it seems like there are like 5 pages on the index page, and arguments index the url specify what will show.

So for example, my profile site http://profile.campatet.com has 3 pages:

- login page
- profile page
- search page.

If the url is `http://profile.campatet.com/?s=something`, it will load `search.php` into the index page and you will see a search page.

If it's `http://profile.campatet.com/?user=something`, it will load `profile.php` into the index page and it will be a user profile.

If it's just `http://profile.campatet.com/`, it will load `login.php` into the index page and  it will be the login page.

Now, the my profile page is loaded into the index page when the index page uses the `readfile()` function. However, the my profile page needs to check a cookie to make sure the person who is accessing the my profile page actually is the account owner.

However, the page can't find the cookie when it is loaded through the `readfile` function for some reason. It works properly when I open it as a independent file, so I know there is nothing wrong with my code for the self profile page.

Why is this happening?

Comment: How are you using PHP in your "sub-pages" if you're loading them with `readfile` (and not, for example, `include`)?

Comment: Why are you using `readfile`? That just sends the contents of the file to the output buffer, it doesn't process PHP inside the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use include or its variants require, require_once etc. instead of readfile()